# Operator overloads between complex numbers defined in customized classes

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I have defined my own complex class `float2_` in the following way

```
class float2_ {

    public:
        float2 c;

        // Member functions
}
```

`float2` is a CUDA `struct`, basically a couple of real and imaginary parts. Similarly, I have defined `int2_` and `double2_` classes.

Now, I would like to overload the `operator+` for all the possible combination of real/complex numbers and complex/complex numbers. Furthermore, in the header file I would like to use templates, to avoid explicitly declaring all those possibilities.

So, what I tried is the following:

```
// .cuh file
template<class A, class B, class C> C operator+(const A,const B);

// .cu file
template float2_::float2_ operator+(const int2_::int2_,const float2_::float2_) 
{ // implementation };
....
```

but this returns me the following error messages:

```
Operator_Overloads.cu(65): error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Operator_Overloads.cu(65): error: invalid explicit instantiation declaration
```

My question is *how correctly implementing `operator+` overloads between all possible combinations of `int`, `float`, `double`, `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_`?

Note that I cannot "templetize" the implementation since different combinations of number additions will have different implementations.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT - PROVISIONAL SOLUTION FOLLOWING THE SUGGESTIONS BY DIETMAR KUEHL**

```
 // Include file
 template<typename T0, typename T1, typename T2> T2 operator+(T0, T1);

 // --- Translational unit

 // --- Auxiliary function add --- complex/complex
 BB::float2_ add(const BB::int2_ a, const BB::float2_ b) { BB::float2_ c; c.c.x = (float)a.c.x + b.c.x; c.c.y = (float)a.c.y + b.c.y; return c; };

 // --- Template definition of operator+
 template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2> T2 operator+(T0 o0, T1 o1) { return add(o0, o1); }

 // --- Instantiation of operator+
 template BB::float2_ operator+<BB::int2_, BB::float2_>(BB::int2_, BB::float2_);
```

**EDIT 2 - WORKING SOLUTION**

```
 // --- Include file
 template <typename, typename> struct result_type;
 template <>
 struct result_type<BB::int2_, BB::float2_> {
      typedef BB::float2_ type;
 };

 template<typename T0, typename T1> typename result_type<T0, T1>::type operator+(T0, T1);

 // --- Translational unit
 BB::float2_ add(const BB::int2_ a, const BB::float2_ b) { BB::float2_ c; c.c.x = (float)a.c.x + b.c.x; c.c.y = (float)a.c.y + b.c.y; return c; };
 BB::float2_ operator+(BB::int2_ a, BB::float2_ b) { return add(a, b); };
```

`BB` is the `namespace` wherein the complex types are defined.

Comment: I would skip the templates entirely and just implement a bunch of overloads.

Comment: @aschepler Why do you recommend that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote an explicit instantiation of an undefined template. You probably meant to write a full specialization:

```
template<>
float2_::float2_ operator+<int2_::int2_, float2_::float2_, float2_::float2_>(
    const int2_::int2_,const float2_::float2_) 
{
    // ...
}
```

I think, however, that anything calling these specializations would actually need to see the declaration of the specializations. Even if this definition is OK, you won't have much fun with it: the return type cannot be deduced, i.e., you need to explicitly specify the return type when calling this operator. I doubt that is what you intend to do. The way to fix the second problem is probably some sort of a traits class which determines the result type based on the argument types. To address the first problem I have implemented the general template delegating to another function and explicitly instantiating it in a translation unit.

Dealing with the return type could look something like this:

```
template <typename, typename> struct result_type;
template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct result_type<int2_::int2_, float2_::float2_> {
    typedef float2_::float2_ type;
};
// other combinations

template <typename T0, typename T1>
typedef typename result_type<T0, T1>::type
operator+(T0, T1);
```

... and the implementation in a translation unit could look something like this:

```
float2_::float2_ add(int2_::int2_ o0, float2_::float2_ o1) {
    ...
}
// more overload of add()

template <typename T0, typename T1>
typedef typename result_type<T0, T1>::type
operator+(T0 o0, T1 o1) {
    return add(o0, o1);
}
template float2_::float2_ operator+<int2_::int2_, float2_::float2_>(
    int2_::int2_, float2_::float2_);
// more explicit instantiations
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your suggestions. Your code does not directly compile, but has provided me with the general idea. I have played a bit, and found a solution that compiles correctly, see my edited post. Unfortunately, when using it in my project, the compiler says that that no operator "+" matches these operands...

Comment: @JackOLantern: your implementation doesn't deal the third template argument: template arguments are not deduced from return types. Thus, you would need to specify the third template argument. Probably you should, instead, determine the return type using a traits type as I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: I think I have a working solution. It compiles and gives the correct result. I have added it to my 2nd edited post. Thank you so much.